# Add other Excel files Sheets to Existing Workbook without changing the formats and colors using Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have loaded the excel files in each workbook and then saved first workbook in the output file (Saved with Entire data and Formatting also) but when i tried to save the second workbook in the same output file it s overwriting. The reason behind this is while saving it is in 'w' mode. I don't find to append new workbook in existing workbook without changing any formats and colors in openpyxl.
**Here how can i Append the new workbooks to the existing workbook without changing the formats ? OR
Is their any other Module where i can fix this issue ? (Not preferring 'Pandas' module since again same issue with formatting and colors)**

Here is the code which i have tried

```
    # Example:

    wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(input_path_1)
    sheets1 = wb1.sheetnames

    wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(input_path_2)
    sheets2 = wb2.sheetnames

    wb1.save(output_path)
    wb2.save(output_path)
```

Comment: This code doesn't make a lot of sense. You repeatedly overwrite files and create lots of empty worksheets.

Comment: You are right but also if we use 'worksheetcopy' copies the  same excel worksheets instead other excel sheets. Can you please suggest me the module or approach to fix this issue ?